# How to add javascript to joomla module?

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla-extensions

Hi I have problem with adding javascript into a joomla module..I've found some solution, but it's not working..

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("/career.js");
```

These two lines I have in my module, but the script isn't in rendered site..
The file is in root of my web (for test purposes only).

Thanks for your help

Comment: When you render the page, do you see the call to the script in the head of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch..The main problem is, that I am loading the page containing custom module with javascript is loaded via ajax..And all the plugins seems to be adding the js code into head and I only replace some elements into body of my page.
exist some solution to this problem?I know I can have all the js logic into one file, but I am not sure it is good way. Is somehow possible to include js directly to module?So that the script tag will be within my document body and correctly included (i am not sure the code will be fired??)

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it's working perfectly.

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('modules'.DS.'MOD_YOURMODULENAME'.DS.'javascript.js');
```

Comment: In newer versions of Joomla, you can use forward slash `/` instead of Joomla Directory Separator `DS`, for example: `$document->addScript('modules/MOD_YOURMODULENAME/javascript.js');`

Answer (score 0):

check the view source .

copy paste the path of the career.js as browser url and try to access it.

Change the path as needed.

```
.   ./   ../
```

Comment: I tried to access directly to the file and it showed properly..But when using addScript, the script is missing:(

Comment: I think that in case of bad url I will find in result code a script tag with src attr which would be set to the value I set??

Answer (score 0):

You can Use  following extension (works both 1.5 and 1.6) to include custom javascript or HTML easily.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules/5435

Also when you use directly may use full path like this (change the path of your .JS)

```
<?php
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript( '/media/system/js/sample.js' );
?>
```

Comment: I tried move it into this folder, without effect..Too tried to incluce another js file from this folder..
I have Joomla 1.5, could it help?
So I will try the extension you wrote about

Comment: So the module is wokring somehow weird:DWhen I write there a js code, it dissappears when rendering, but regular text displays properly. I tried both settings for clean html and js..

Comment: im having the same issue, im going to try this tonight

Answer (score 0):

So only workaround which works for me is to add this js to template of my site..But its really awful solution, since I only need it in one article/module

Comment: i think we can have different templates for home page and inner page.is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the joomla php module
http://www.fijiwebdesign.com/products/joomla-php-module.html
or maybe you found a module that better fits your needs at:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have this

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

after head tag in template index.php

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are landing on this page at a much later date, and looking for solution in Joomla 3.x

You can include a module of type "Custom HTML Advanced" which will NOT filter out any script or style tags.
You can use it on any of the pages you want.

Hope this helps you :)